# Increase column value ONLY if below 100

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Ok I have a question that may not be possible without selecting data first and seeing if the column is below 100.. but anyway. I'm hoping there is an easier way to do this so I don't have to run two queries.
I only want to update the column if it's less than 100 + whatever I'm adding.

I'm using CI:

```
$this->db->set('happiness', 'happiness + '.$amt['happiness'], FALSE);
$this->db->set('loyalty', 'loyalty + '.$amt['loyalty'], FALSE);
$this->db->set('hunger', 'hunger + '.$amt['hunger'], FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', $creature);
$this->db->update('user_creature');
```

The thing is is that SOMETIMES the happiness may already be at 94 and I'm adding 9.. Which will make it 103.. But the MAX value I want to be able to have it at is 100.. So if it's going to make it equal or greater than 100, I rather just update it to 100.
Is there anyway you can do that in MySQL syntax? Any function?

Right now I'm only thinking I have to select the data and see if the math will make it greater than 100, if so, just type 100, if not, then do my equations I have up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [MySQL's LEAST function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least).  Not too familiar with Codeigniter's DB syntax, but here's the idea in plain PHP:

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE user_creature
    SET happiness = LEAST(100, happiness + $amt[hunger])
    WHERE id = $creature
";
```

Comment: Updated my answer, originally said `MIN` but function is actually `LEAST`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add it to your WHERE clause also?

```
 WHERE (happiness + {$amt['happiness']}) <= 100
```

Comment: Because then if that returns false, it won't update the column at all and it will stay at 94, when I would still want it to update to the 100 point.. If it's gonna go FARTHER than 100, I want to still at least update it to 100.. Not keep it at 94.

Comment: This won't update `happiness` to 100 if it would otherwise be updated to `> 100`.

Comment: Ah yes - then as @Madbreaks suggested, `MIN` is what you want!